# A simple VHDL circuit won't display initial value

Tags: vhdl, quartus-ii, cyclone

Here is my code and it's pretty simple. I'm to cycle through the first 8 letters of the alphabet on a Altera Cyclone II board.

```
entity lettercycle is
    port(
        SW  : in  std_logic; -- toggle switch
        HEX0 : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) -- 7-segment display
        );
end lettercycle;

architecture behavioural of lettercycle is
    signal counter : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;
begin
    process
        type SEGMENT_ARRAY is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        variable SEVENSEG : SEGMENT_ARRAY := ("0001000","0000011","1000110","0100001","0000110","0001110","0010000","0001001");
        begin
        HEX0 <= SEVENSEG(counter);
        wait until SW = '0';
        counter <= counter + 1;
        end process;
end behavioural;
```

This works great, it cycles but initially it doesn't display "A" on my seven segment display. It displays "8" (so nothing essentially). Once I push SW which is a logic 0 switch it changes to 'A' and cycles to 'B', 'C', etc properly. It also loops correctly. What it isn't doing is initially setting to 'A'. If I force

```
    HEX0 <= SEVENSEG(0);
```

Then it will display 'A' initially so I'm out ideas. Could this be related to bouncing?

Comment: You don't need to (and probably shouldn't) duplicate questions both here and on stackoverflow.  Anyone who might answer will see both. Guess which one garnered more attention?  (Due to the relative number of question posts).

Comment: Agreed. I had actually asked the question over there first, then clicked a question in the sidebar and saw it was downvoted for not posting here. So I posted here but didn't remove the initial question over there (I don't think you can delete actually). Anyway mistake made. Sorry.

Comment: Don't have access to the voting history but it'd likely wrong to down vote it as being 'in the wrong place',  sounds like tilting at windmills. The majority of VHDL questions are opened there. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates "Why are some questions marked as duplicate?"), which explains why it's desirable to have all the answers in one place. Also [Why and how are some questions deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions "Why and how are some questions deleted?") for when a user can delete their own question.

Comment: The remaining question is, are you satisfied witht he answer's you received?

Comment: Absolutely. Changing SEVENSEG to a constant and moving the HEX0 assignment outside the process is what I needed to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing "counter : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;"

So initially the value of counter = 0000000. So at the start of this loop

```
begin
HEX0 <= SEVENSEG(counter);
wait until SW = '0';
counter <= counter + 1;
end process;
```

counter is all zeros. So obviously it will display 8 on 7-seg. Try using

```
counter : integer range 0 to 7 := "0001000"
```

This will set your counter value to A initially.

Comment: See the duplicate question on Stackexchange - [A simple VHDL circuit won't display initial value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797127/a-simple-vhdl-circuit-wont-display-initial-value "A simple VHDL circuit won't display initial value").  Check out Morten's answer in particular.  The issue is that there is an inferred register on HEX0 that is initialized to all '0's by default.